# How to Unit test the java code

Tags: java, junit

How to unit test this code using Junit

```
public class Diamond {

   public void DiamondShape(int num) {

       for(int ucount=num;ucount>0;ucount--) {
    //Loop to print blank space
        for(int count_sp=1;count_sp<ucount;count_sp++)
            System.out.printf(" ");
    //Loop to print *
        for(int count_ast=num;count_ast>=ucount;count_ast--)
            System.out.printf("* ");
        System.out.println();
       }
//Loop for lower half
  for(int lcount=1;lcount<num;lcount++) {
    //Loop to print blank space
    for(int count_sp=0;count_sp<lcount;count_sp++)
            System.out.printf(" ");
    //Loop to print *
        for(int count_ast=num-1;count_ast>=lcount;count_ast--)
            System.out.printf("* ");
    System.out.println();
    }
  } 
}
```

I am new at unit testing want some guidance on unit testing .

Output when num=3

```
   *
  * *
 * * *
  * *
   *
```

this is how the output should be, num indicates the star in center line

Comment: Why are you doing so much stuff in that constructor ?

Comment: It's not a constructor (it has a return type of `void`); it just looks like one because it starts with a capital letter.

Comment: .. and what are you trying to test? that you print to console?

Comment: This isn't optimized then how can I optimize it

Comment: i want to print a diamond shape with *     *
   *

Comment: Typically, your unit test would be one test method per call to `DiamondShape(int num)` and assert that the expected thing is done. If the method returns something, this is trivial, just assert on the return value. Since you are only printing to standard output, it is harder. It can surely be done in someway though.

Comment: @NairAjit For feedback on how your code can be improved, you can consult our sister site codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: *
  * *
   *
somewhat like this when the value of num is 2
num indicates the stars in center line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of printing your shape directly you could store the shape in an `ArrayList<String>`

```
public class Diamond {
    private List<String> shape = null;

    public void createShape(int num) {
        shape = new ArrayList<String>();
        String shapeLine = "";
        for(int ucount=num;ucount>0;ucount--) {
            for(int count_sp=1;count_sp<ucount;count_sp++) {
                shapeLine += " ";
            }
            for(int count_ast=num;count_ast>=ucount;count_ast--) {
                shapeLine += "* ";
            }
            shape.add(shapeLine);
        }

        shapeLine = "";
        for(int lcount=1;lcount<num;lcount++) {
           for(int count_sp=0;count_sp<lcount;count_sp++) {
                shapeLine += " ";
           }
           for(int count_ast=num-1;count_ast>=lcount;count_ast--) {
               shapeLine += "* ";
           }
           shape.Add(shapeLine);
        }
    } 

    public void printShape(OutStream out) {
        if(shape != null) {
            for(String shapeLine : shape) {
                out.println(shapeLine);
            }
        }
    }

    public List<String> getShape() {
        return shape;
    } 
}
```

now you can test your code:

```
@Test
public void testShape() {
    Diamond diamond = new Diamond();
    diamond.createShape(3);
    List<String> shape = diamond.getShape();

    assertNotNull(shape);
    assertEquals(5, shape.size());
    assertEquals("  * ", shape.get(0));
    assertEquals(" * * ", shape.get(1));
    assertEquals("* * * ", shape.get(2));
    assertEquals(" * * ", shape.get(3));
    assertEquals("  * ", shape.get(4));
}
```

to print your shape simply call

```
diamond.printShape(System.out);
```

the inner part of you loops for the upper and lower half are quite the same and could be refactored into an own method.

Comment: Thank you so much I think this will do

Comment: next stop: write a test for the print method ;)

Comment: The List is not providing the correct output as it is printing everything
  * 
  * ** 
  * ** ***

Comment: I am printing the output below ur answer

Comment: if the test fails something is wrong with your loops. if the leading spaces are missing then you should check the loop that prepends the spaces

Comment: the problem is not with loop but when getting the data from the list for ex get(2) it will print (0) (1) then (2)

Comment: how do you access the list to print?

Comment: for (int size = 0; size < numLine; size++) {
   System.out.println(shape.get(size));
  }

Comment: what is numLine? does the test pass?

Comment: see the edit above it had made the first half of the shape but bottom half is still not coming

Comment: consider numLine as 3 for now

Comment: this means you only retrieve 3 of 5 lines from the list. why don't you just call the printShape() method?

Comment: sorry man a silly mistake this time I changed numLine to shape.size()
and made shapeLine =""; inside the loop it worked

Comment: still wondering why you are iteration over shape at all and not just call printShape() ;)

Comment: But still you have to clear the String shapeLine inside the loop

Comment: one last thing: you should extend the testcase to check if shape creation works for other numbers and not just for 3

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing sysout you should refactor and make your method return the output. You can then verify the output.

The other option is in your junit test create a Output stream and set it on the

```
System.setOut(your output stream);
```

You can then verify the output stream.

But this is not reliable as if your program executes some other code which also writing to the sysout then your output stream will have that data also.

Comment: Returning the value is tough because there are too many values

Comment: @NairAjit You can return a single String with the complete output. Strings can include line-breaks.

Comment: @NairAjit Or pass a PrintStream object to the method which is used for output like described in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In order to test a method it has to do one of these:

- return a value you can compare with an expected value
- change the state of an object which gets passed to it
- throw an exception you can catch
- change some state of the object which you can verify by calling another method

For that reason, methods which returns void and just write their result to System.out should generally be avoided.

To fix this issue you can do one of these:

- Return a String instead of writing to stdout.
- Make the method take an [PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) object and write to that. System.out is a PrintStream object, so you can pass it in production code. In your test code, however, you can pass your own PrintStream object which doesn't write to stdout but instead allows to check what was written to it. This technique is called [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection).
- Make the method write to a private PrintStream or String, and add two new methods to the class. One to get the content of that variable so you can test that it is correct and one to write that variable to System.out.

Comment: Thanks I think it will be quite helpful let me try as you said